# Code works in Firefox and Safari, but not IE or Chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps, google-chrome, safari

The code below works great in Firefox and Safari, no issues. In IE, the markers don't load at all and in Chrome, the markers load but when you click on a marker, the infobox does not pop up. If you click in on the side menu it does pop up.  Any ideas? Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <title>Activities</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false""></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="GoogleMaps/Scripts/downloadxml.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="GoogleMaps/Scripts/infobubble_tabs.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
html, body { height: 100%; } 
    .style1
    {
        width: 758px;
    }
    .style2
    {        
        width: 349px;
    }
#side_bar  
{
    height: 550px;
    width: 349px;   
    overflow:scroll;
}
</style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        // this variable will collect the html which will eventually be placed in the side_bar 
        var side_bar_html = "";
        var gmarkers = [];
        var gicons = [];
        var map = null;

        var InfoBubble = new InfoBubble({
            maxWidth: 300
        });


        //defines icon if there is none stated
        gicons["red"] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_red.png",
      new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      new google.maps.Point(9, 9));
        // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y
        // where the origin of the image (0,0) is located
        // in the top left of the image.
        // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker
        // increase in the X direction to the right and in
        // the Y direction down.

        var iconImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_red.png',
        new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      new google.maps.Point(9, 9));
        var iconShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png',
      new google.maps.Size(37, 34),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      new google.maps.Point(9, 9));
        // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
        // The type defines an HTML &lt;area&gt; element 'poly' which traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final coordinate closes 
        //the poly by connecting to the first coordinate.
        var iconShape = {
            coord: [9, 0, 6, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 0, 8, 0, 12, 1, 14, 2, 16, 5, 19, 7, 23, 8, 26, 9, 30, 9, 34, 11, 34, 11, 30, 12, 26, 13, 24, 14, 21, 16, 18, 18, 16, 20, 12, 20, 8, 18, 4, 16, 2, 15, 1, 13, 0],
            type: 'poly'
        };

        //determines icon based on category
        //if no icon is defined
        function getMarkerImage(iconColor) {
            if ((typeof (iconColor) == "undefined") || (iconColor == null)) {
                iconColor = "red";
            }
            if (!gicons[iconColor]) {
                gicons[iconColor] = new google.maps.MarkerImage(iconColor,
      new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      new google.maps.Point(9, 9));
            }
            return gicons[iconColor];
        }

        function category2icon(category) {
            var color = "red";
            switch (category) {
                case "Hike": color = "GoogleMaps/Images/HikingIcon.jpg";
                    break;
                case "KML": color = "GoogleMaps/Images/kml.gif";
                    break;
                case "Camping": color = "GoogleMaps/Images/camping.gif";
                    break;
                case "StatePark": color = "GoogleMaps/Images/statepark.jpg";
                    break;
                case "NationalPark": color = "GoogleMaps/Images/NationalPark_icon.png";
                    break;
                case "PointsofInterest": color = "GoogleMaps/Images/POI.png";
                    break;
                case "CountyPark": color = "GoogleMaps/Images/CountyPark_Icon.png";
                    break;
                case "Biking": color = "GoogleMaps/Images/Bike_icon.jpg";
                    break;
                case "FishWildlifeService": color = "GoogleMaps/Images/FishWildlife_icon.gif";
                    break;
                case "Kayak": color = "GoogleMaps/Images/kayaking.png";
                    break;
                case "Shelter": color = "GoogleMaps/Images/Shelter_Icon.png";
                    break;
                case "Parking": color = "GoogleMaps/Images/Parking_Lot_Icon.png";
                    break;               
                default: color = "red";
                    break;
            }
            return color;
        }

        gicons["Hike"] = getMarkerImage(category2icon("Hike"));
        gicons["KML"] = getMarkerImage(category2icon("KML"));
        gicons["Camping"] = getMarkerImage(category2icon("Camping"));
        gicons["StatePark"] = getMarkerImage(category2icon("StatePark"));
        gicons["NationalPark"] = getMarkerImage(category2icon("NationalPark"));
        gicons["PointsofInterest"] = getMarkerImage(category2icon("PointsofInterest"));
        gicons["CountyPark"] = getMarkerImage(category2icon("CountyPark"));
        gicons["Biking"] = getMarkerImage(category2icon("Biking"));
        gicons["FishWildlifeService"] = getMarkerImage(category2icon("FishWildlifeService"));
        gicons["Kayak"] = getMarkerImage(category2icon("Kayak"));
        gicons["Shelter"] = getMarkerImage(category2icon("Shelter"));
        gicons["Parking"] = getMarkerImage(category2icon("Parking"));

        // A function to create the marker and set up the event window
        function createMarker(latlng, name, url, detail_tab, notes_tab, map_tab, hiking_detail_tab, camping_detail_tab, category, state) {
            var contentString_detail = detail_tab;
            var contentString_notes = notes_tab;
            var contentString_maps = map_tab;
            var contentString_hiking_detail = hiking_detail_tab;
            var contentString_camping_detail = camping_detail_tab;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                icon: gicons[category],
                shadow: iconShadow,
                map: map,
                title: name,
                zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
            });
            // === Store the category and name info as a marker properties ===
            marker.mycategory = category;
            marker.mystate = state;
            marker.myname = name;
            gmarkers.push(marker);

            // to open the info bubbles
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                InfoBubble.open(map, marker);
                InfoBubble.removeTab(4);
                InfoBubble.removeTab(3);
                InfoBubble.removeTab(2);
                InfoBubble.removeTab(1);
                InfoBubble.removeTab(0);
                if (category == "KML") {
                    window.open("" + url);
                }
                if (!category == "KML") {
                    InfoBubble.addTab('Details', contentString_detail);
                }
                if (!notes_tab == "") {
                    InfoBubble.addTab('Notes', contentString_notes);
                }
                if (!map_tab == "") {
                    switch (category) {
                        case "Camping": InfoBubble.addTab('Campsite Map', contentString_maps);
                            break;
                        case "Hike": InfoBubble.addTab('Trail Map', contentString_maps);
                            break;
                }
                }
                if (!hiking_detail_tab == "") {
                    InfoBubble.addTab('Trail Notes', contentString_hiking_detail);
                }
                if (!camping_detail_tab == "") {
                    InfoBubble.addTab('Campsite Notes', contentString_camping_detail);
                }
            });
        }

        // == shows all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==
        function show(category) {
            for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
                if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
                    gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
                }
            }
            // == check the checkbox ==
            document.getElementById(category + "box").checked = true;
        }

        // == hides all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is cleared ==
        function hide(category) {
            for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
                if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
                    gmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
                }
            }
            // == clear the checkbox ==
            document.getElementById(category + "box").checked = false;
            // == close the info window, in case its open on a marker that we just hid
            InfoBubble.close();
        }

        // == a checkbox has been clicked ==
        function boxclick(box, category) {
            if (box.checked) {
                show(category);
            } else {
                hide(category);
            }
            // == rebuild the side bar
            makeSidebar();
        }

        function myclick(i) {
            google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
        }

        // == rebuilds the sidebar to match the markers currently displayed ==
        function makeSidebar() {
            var html = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
                if (gmarkers[i].getVisible()) {
                    html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + gmarkers[i].myname + '<\/a><br>';
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = html;
        }

        function initialize() {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.364032, -77.182159),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

            // Closes any open bubbles before opening new one
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function () {                
                InfoBubble.close();
            });

            //Downloads the data from xml file
            // Reads the data the creates each tab
            downloadUrl("GoogleMaps/categories.xml", function (doc) {
                var xml = xmlParse(doc);
                var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    // obtain the attribues of each marker
                    var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
                    var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
                    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                    var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
                    var city = markers[i].getAttribute("city");
                    var state = markers[i].getAttribute("state");
                    var zip = markers[i].getAttribute("zip");
                    var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
                    var notes = markers[i].getAttribute("notes");
                    var url = markers[i].getAttribute("url");
                    var hike_distance = markers[i].getAttribute("hike_distance");
                    var hike_trail_skill_level = markers[i].getAttribute("hike_trail_skill_level");
                    var hike_points_of_interest = markers[i].getAttribute("hike_points_of_interest");
                    var Camping_Amenities = markers[i].getAttribute("Camping_Amenities");
                    var Camping_Best_Sites = markers[i].getAttribute("Camping_Best_Sites");
                    var Camping_Notes = markers[i].getAttribute("Camping_Notes");
                    var image = markers[i].getAttribute("image");
                    var category = markers[i].getAttribute("category");
                    //Creates data for Detail Tab
                    var detail_tab = "";
                    detail_tab += "<b>" + name + "<\/b><p>";
                    detail_tab += address + "</br>";
                    detail_tab += city + ", " + state + " " + zip + "</br>";
                    detail_tab += '<br><a target="_blank" href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>' + "</br>";
                    //Creates data for Notes Tab
                    var notes_tab = notes;
                    //Creates data for Maps Tab
                    var map_tab = "";
                    if (image) {
                        map_tab += '<br><a target="_blank" href="' + image + '">' + image + '</a>' + "</br>";
                    }
                    //Creates data for Hiking Detail Tab                    
                    var hiking_detail_tab = "";
                    if (hike_distance) {
                        hiking_detail_tab += "<b>Trail Distance: </b>" + hike_distance + " miles</br>";
                        hiking_detail_tab += "<b>Trail Skill Level: </b>" + hike_trail_skill_level + "</br>";
                        hiking_detail_tab += "<b>Points of Interest: </b>" + hike_points_of_interest + "</br>";
                    }
                    //Creates data for Camping Detail Tab                    
                    var camping_detail_tab = "";
                    if (Camping_Notes) {
                        camping_detail_tab += "<b>Amenities: </b>" + Camping_Amenities + "</br>";
                        camping_detail_tab += "<b>Best Sites: </b>" + Camping_Best_Sites + "</br>";
                        camping_detail_tab += "<b>Notes: </b>" + Camping_Notes + "</br>";
                    }
                   // var kml_tab = "";
                   // if (category=="KML) {
                    // create the marker
                    var marker = createMarker(point, name, url, detail_tab, notes_tab, map_tab, hiking_detail_tab, camping_detail_tab, category);
                }

                // == show or hide the categories initially ==
                show("Hike");
                show("KML");
                hide("Camping");
                hide("StatePark");
                hide("NationalPark");
                hide("PointsofInterest");
                hide("CountyPark");
                hide("Biking");
                hide("FishWildlifeService");
                hide("Kayak");
                hide("Shelter");
                hide("Parking");
                // == create the initial sidebar ==
                makeSidebar();
            });
        }


    //]]>
    </script>
  </head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()"> 
    <table border="1" >
      <tr>
        <td class="style1">
           <div id="map" style="width:978px; height: 596px"></div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #4444ff;" 
              class="style2">
              <h4>To view a topo map, click map in the top left corner and select terrain from drop down menu</h4> 
           <div id="side_bar"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <form action="#">
      Hiking: <input type="checkbox" id="Hikebox" onclick="boxclick(this,'Hike')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      Full Trail Map: <input type="checkbox" id="KMLbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'KML')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      Trail Shelters: <input type="checkbox" id="Shelterbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'Shelter')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      Trail Parking: <input type="checkbox" id="Parkingbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'Parking')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      Camping: <input type="checkbox" id="Campingbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'Camping')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      Biking: <input type="checkbox" id="Bikingbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'Biking')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      Kayaking: <input type="checkbox" id="Kayakbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'Kayak')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <br />
      State Parks: <input type="checkbox" id="StateParkbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'StatePark')" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
      National Parks: <input type="checkbox" id="NationalParkbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'NationalPark')" />&nbsp;&nbsp;   
      County Park: <input type="checkbox" id="CountyParkbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'CountyPark')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <br />
      Points of Interest: <input type="checkbox" id="PointsofInterestbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'PointsofInterest')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;  
      Fish and Wildlife Service: <input type="checkbox" id="FishWildlifeServicebox" onclick="boxclick(this,'FishWildlifeService')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;      
      <br />
    </form>  




    <noscript><b>JavaScript must be enabled in order for you to use Google Maps.</b> 
      However, it seems JavaScript is either disabled or not supported by your browser. 
      To view Google Maps, enable JavaScript by changing your browser options, and then 
      try again.
    </noscript>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you please refine the code sample used in this question? If you're going to use **so** much code, then it would be nice to see the example in action, or at minimum create a JSFiddle.

Comment: It's not even runnable. The console gets full of missing dependencies.  Also there is an extra quote in the first <script> tag, and it should be `&amp;sensor=false"` and not `&sensor=false"`.

Comment: clear everything off of your page add few by few codes and keep running it in ie till you find the exact problematic area and paste that code alone in the question

Comment: Does your XML work if you point IE at it or does IE complain that it isn't valid?

Comment: Sorry guys, I figured it would be a tag issue so I posted the whole code. The extra quote was a typo and isn't in the code that is not working. Thanks for that. I tried clearing stuff off and can't narrow down where the issue is. IE doesn't complain, it just doesn't load the markers. Here is a link to it in action http://www.troop993bac.org/htmlpage12.htm

Comment: OK, got the IE part working. The XML had an invalid character but it really didn't, simply resaved the XML and it started working. So the only issue I now have is that in Chrome, when you click a marker, the popup won't come up.

Comment: The linked page works fine for me, also in chrome & IE. Maybe this is a caching-issue. Try to change the url provided to `downloadUrl()` into `"GoogleMaps/categories.xml?"+new Date().getTime()` to avoid the caching of the xml-file

Comment: Additionally: be sure that you are testing the same page on each browser. In the code posted above you've included [infobubble_tabs.js](http://www.troop993bac.org/GoogleMaps/Scripts/infobubble_tabs.js) which doesn't exist on the server, while on the linked page you have included infobox.js(which exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message I get in IE (9) is:

XML5617: Illegal XML character. 
, line 7858 character 243

> hike_points_of_interest="Arguably the prettiest trail in the Loch Raven Reservoir watershed. Follow it to Merryman Point, where the reservoir spreads out in several directions. From the parking area, you have several options to begin the hike�the trailhead farthest to the right leads to a narrow path that runs alongside the reservoir, the farthest to the left runs to a fire road, and the second to the left (the one I take) runs along a wide path but not before going along a narrower path, which will eventually afford nice views of the reservoir and give you the option of linking with the fire road."

Comment: I found that one and added a comment, but don't see it now. That fixed the IE issue, so thank you. My only issue now is chrome won't open the info bubble when you click a marker.